# How do I fix missing anti-aliasing in the Unity scene view and game?

Tags: unity, rendering, antialiasing

[image: Screenshot of scene view]

Both the editor and the game seem to lack anti-aliasing even though quality is set to Ultra.

I chose the "3D" project template when I created the project, so I am using the build-in render pipeline.

Comment: I didn't change any setting so I'm guessing the default one? Sorry, I'm afraid I'm very new to Unity.

Comment: I've opened a new project with URP, anti aliasing does not seem to be enabled either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Unity editor doesn't perform anti-aliasing directly any more, unfortunately. You're expected to add it as a Post Processing effect via the Post Processing stack (see https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@3.2).